# RODBC sqlQuery as.is returning bad results

Tags: r, rodbc

I'm trying to import an excel worksheet into R. I want to retrieve a (character) ID column and a couple of date columns from the worksheet. The following code works fine but brings one column in as a date and not another. I think it has something to do with more leading columns being empty in the second date field.

```
dateFile <- odbcConnectExcel2007(xcelFile)
query <- "SELECT ANIMALID, ST_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME FROM [KNWR_CL$]"
idsAndDates <- sqlQuery(dateFile,query)
```

So my plan now is to bring in the date columns as character fields and convert them myself using as.POSIXct. However, the following code produces only a single row in idsAndDates.

```
dateFile <- odbcConnectExcel2007(xcelFile)
query <- "SELECT ANIMALID, ST_DATE_TIME, END_DATE_TIME FROM [KNWR_CL$]"
idsAndDates <- sqlQuery(dateFile,query,as.is=TRUE,TRUE,TRUE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `as.is=c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks. I now get all the rows. And the dates are now character fields. But it looks like the first was first converted to a Date and then converted to a character field. In excel they're both in MM/DD/YY HH:MM format but in R the first is now in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format. Which is what it looked like before I did the as.is stuff. The second is formatted like in excel.

Comment: Few shots: try `na.strings=""` or `believeNRows=FALSE` (or both). And make sure that under Excel this fields are dates (i.e. not stored as text).

Comment: For the record: I could not reproduce (use R-2.13, 32bit).

Comment: Neither of those ideas worked. I am using R-2.11 64 bit. I tried it in 32-bit R (using odbcConnect) but the results were worse. When you tried to replicate it, which string type resulted? YYYY-MM-DD HH... or MM/DD/YY HH...? Also, in my file the second date column has 9 empty rows before the first date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to move on and ended up using the gdata library (which worked). I'd still be interested in an answer for this though.